# Weird SSRS reports error while Depolying reports

Tags: sql-server, ssrs, reporting, ssrs-2016

I have created the reports by using SSRS 2016 and Visual Studio 2015.
When I build the reports it shows success, then deploying the report to the Target server URL I get the following error:

> Microsoft SQL Server Report Designer:
>
> Could not connect to the report server http://ServerName/ReportServer_InstanceName.
>   Verify that the TargetServerURL is valid and that you have the correct
>   permissions to connect to the report server.
>
> Additional Info: Unable to connect to the Remote server

I got the report sever URL from the configured Reporting Services:

It's a named instance so I added WEB Server URL as:  `http://servername/reportserver_instancename` and I checked permission all are in place.

Is there any reason behind the URL or Permissions issue?

Comment: Are you running VS as Administrator?

Comment: @HenricoBekker, No. I am running VS as a user and I have all permissions for that.

Comment: Right-click on Visual Studio executable, select Run as Administrator.

Comment: @HenricoBekker, Yeah I did it, again it shows same error like before

Comment: Are you able to manually upload an RDL successfully?

Comment: Is the Report Server running?

Comment: If you asking about Report server DB in SSMS, yes it's running

Comment: @HenricoBekker, I am able to do manual upload RDL successfully.

Comment: Confirm the report server url is correct in the project deployment properties too.

Comment: Based on RSCM Report server - Web service URL is "http://<serverName>/ReportServer_InstanceName" and WEB Portal URL is "http://<serverName>/ReportServer", I think URL is correct? and project deployment properties - Configuration (Release) and Target URL - "http://<serverName>/ReportServer"

Comment: I changed the deployment properties Configuration (Release) and Target URL - "http://<serverName>/Reports" , Because my Web service URL is "http://<serverName>/ReportServer" and WEB Portal URL is "http://<serverName>/Reports". I think my Target URL  must be same as WEB Portal URL. It's working fine now and I am able to deploy reports from VS after many changes. Thanks for help @HenricoBekker

Comment: Open the reporting services configuration manager. Connect to you service. What does it say the URL is?

Comment: Check your permissions on the report server.  I believe you must be a Publisher on the folder you are trying to deploy to.